# How to set config.xml for cordova 3.5 contacts plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have added the cordova Contacts plugin to a project as follows:
% cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts
Then did a build like this:
% cordova build ios

But the plugin is unusable - no code that refers to it gets run.  The app just stops at that point.  When I look in the cordova docs at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts/blob/master/doc/index.md  there's nothing about setting config.xml.  My curent config looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.OurApp.OurApp" version="0.0.1"     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Our App</name>
    <description>
        Our descriptions.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@ourteam.com" href="http://cordova.io">
        Our Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

I know that the build was supposed to update config.xml, but it didn't.  What do I need to add to get ver 3.5 Contacts to work?  And is there a list of all these config settings somewhere?  TIA.

EDIT: I tried adding

```
<plugin name="Contacts" value="CDVContacts" />
```

within the widget tag - no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking into config.xml of root folder. Please note now cordova maintaines two config files. One at root folder which have setting related to app. There is second config file at platform/ios/projectName/config.xml. this is the final config xml with all plugin related details. Please look into this config after build command. plugins must be there if they are installed. you can see all the installed plugins using command 
cordova plugin plugin-list

I hope It will give you right direction. If it won't help, Please post error message from console.

Comment: Thanks Rupesh.  I did not know about the 2nd config.xml file in the platforms/ios/project directory.  That looks like it's OK.  I am getting two error messages from the console:  

"Error:ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ContactFindOptions in undefined at line..."  I don't think this one is crucial - it's the next one:

"Error: Error: Module org.apache.cordova.contacts.contacts does not exist.  in undefined at line..."  In my plugins/ directory there is a org.apache.cordova.contacts directory, put there by the install process.  Adding a ".contacts" to the name does not help.